# SOAP request from wsdl without automatic generation of JAVA classes

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, soap-client, wsdl2java

I'm putting together an api that generates a soap connection with java, and I wanted to put together this request from wsdl without the need for auto generation of classes and without the need to manually put together the body of the soap request, more or less the same as the interface soap ui does, I was unable to use their API because maven is saying that it is deprecated and some of the libraries I tested are discontinued as it is an older technology, and I wanted to know if anyone has done something similar to be able to shed some light on this.

I've already tested libraries like soap ui, apachecxf, jakarta